# Docker rootless mode setup tool script can't find slirp4netns binary

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, static-libraries

I am trying to set up Docker rootless mode on Ubuntu 18.04, using the `dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh` script. But I'm struggling to get the script to find the [slirp4netns](https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns) binary I downloaded (slirp4netns provides user-mode networking for unprivileged network namespaces). On Ubuntu 20 this is installable as a package using `apt`, but for lower Ubuntu versions a pre-built binary is provided [here](https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns/releases/tag/v1.1.12).

I am running the script (as non-root) with:

```
dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install
```

But it complains:

```
Either slirp4netns (>= v0.4.0) or vpnkit needs to be installed
```

I have downloaded the latest stable binary for slirp4netns (v1.1.12) as per the instructions:

```
curl -o slirp4netns --fail -L https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns/releases/download/v1.1.12/slirp4netns-$(uname -m)
chmod +x slirp4netns
```

I moved the binary (as root) to `/usr/local/lib`. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to update an environment variable? I don't really want to upgrade my entire OS just to get a single library.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the binary is supposed to be in your `$PATH` somewhere? That would be e.g. `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @larsks Gosh, how stupid am I? I had assumed /usr/local/lib was on PATH, but in fact it's not. If only I'd checked. Moving the binary to /usr/local/bin solved this!

Answer (score 0):

It was my own stupidity. As the person says in the comment to my question, all I needed to do was to move the binary to `/usr/local/bin`. I had assumed `/usr/local/lib` was on `PATH`, but it wasn't.